# Page columns in Interop Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

Does any one know how to split a word document into columns using c#, At a specific point.

```
doc.Sections.PageSetup.TextColumns.SetCount(2);
```

The above code does the complete document, Not just from a specific point

Comment: You need to introduce a section break so that the columns can apply to a section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have located or navigated to the *specific point*,

```
Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakContinuous
```

is the VBA code that would insert a (continuous) section break.

(From C# `Selection` is preceded by the reference to the Word Application.)

Then

```
doc.Sections(1).PageSetup.TextColumns.SetCount(2);
```

would apply the columns to section one.

Comment: This also worked for me 'Paragraph p = doc.Paragraphs.Add();
                p.Range.PageSetup.TextColumns.SetCount(2);'

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to set columns from a specific point to the end of doc.

```
object oMissing = Missing.Value;
object oEndOfDoc = "\\endofdoc";
//Start Word and create a new document.
Word._Application oWord;
Word._Document oDoc;
oWord = new Word.Application();
oWord.Visible = true;
oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing,ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

//here you insert your paragraphs...

oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range.InsertBreak(Word.WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakContinuous);
oDoc.Sections[2].PageSetup.TextColumns.SetCount(2);
```